# Gerar linhas com inputs em javascript

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Quero criar um sistema pra inserção de informações em um banco de dados, de forma que eu possa mostrar ao usuário em tabela aonde cada info irá ficar, colocando cada input em uma célula.
Assim, ao apertar o botão "Adicionar informação", deve-se gerar uma nova linha contendo o formulário e  a linha com os inputs conforme o codigo abaixo:

```
<button onclick="adicionar('tbody')">Adicionar linha+</button>
<table id="tabelado">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item 1</th>
            <th>funções</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
   
        <tr>
            <td>valor 1</td>
            <td><button>Apagar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function adicionar(tableID){
        let tableRef = document.getElementById(tableID);
        let row = tableRef.insertRow(0);
        row.innerHTML = `<form>
    <td>
        <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
       <button type="submit">enviar</button>
    </td>
</form> `;
    }
</script>
```

Eu esperava que criasse um código assim:

```
    <form>
    <td>
        <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
       <button type="submit">enviar</button>
    </td>
</form>
```

Mas por algum motivo fica com a tag "form" isolada:

```
    <form></form>
    <td>
        <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
       <button type="submit">enviar</button>
    </td>
```

Já tô a um tempo tentando corrigir, mas não faço mais ideia de como consertar, se puderem me dar uma luz, eu agradeço.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Gerar linhas com inputs em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/587937/gerar-linhas-com-inputs-em-javascript)

Comment: Considerando que [esta postagem está duplicada](/q/587937/70), o campo de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode editar a pergunta original conforme orientações dadas lá.